# Request active button status

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I use Bootstrap in combination with Spring Boot / MVC and thymeleaf

At the moment I have a button which can be pressed by the user and is marked active then.

But my problem is, that I cannot receive the status of that button in my backend.

For example if I use the checkbox feature I can get the status via

```
  <td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="true" name="checkboxvalue"/></label></td>
```

And access the status via that way:

```
    httpEntity.getBody().contains("checkboxvalue")
```

**And now the active button part what my question is about**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="template :: head">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="specifyDetails">
        <h2>Chose what you want to trade</h2>
        <label>
            <select th:name="Products" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="productList" type="java.util.List"*/-->
                <option th:each="product : ${productList}"><a th:text="${product}"></a></option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button th:type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
    </form>
    <form><a th:href="'orderview/'" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">Orderview only</a>
    </form>
<input th:type="button" id="activeButton" name="basketOrders" class="btn btn-info" value="true"/>


<div th:replace="template :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the **template.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:fragment="head">
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <!--/*@thymesVar id="title" type="String"*/-->
        <title th:text="${title}">Library trader</title>
    </head>

   <footer th:fragment="footer">
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js}"></script>
    <script>$('#activeButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })</script>


    <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</footer>
```

When I now call httpEntity.getBody() I don't have any information about that button in the body...no matter if the button was pressed or not.

So please tell me, how I can get access to the status of the button. Thank you very much.

Comment: you can use jquery ajax to send your button status to your controller

Comment: can you please explain me how I do that or what I have to add in my code?

Comment: Can you add your controller part to get better answer, then i can add answer with jquery ajax with specified url (Controller Name, Action Name)